# UMVU etimator for gamma distribution with unknown alpha

Tags: parameter-estimation, gamma-distribution

Given $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ random samples from $gamma(α,β)$ with unknown $α$.  What will be the "Uniform minimum variance unbaised" Estimator for $α$ and $β$.

If $α$ is known then we know the UMVUE for $1/β$ is $(nα-1)/(\sum X_i)$. But can you please help with what if $α$ is unknown? i.e. what will be the estmator of $α$ and $β$.

Comment: I've seen BLUE="Best linear unbiased estimator" and MVUE= "minimum variance unbiased estimator". Is UMVUE the same thing or something else?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor $UMVUE$ is "Uniform minimum variance unbiased estimator"